# Add help to "No help available" Excel, VBA , User defined functions

Tags: excel, excel-2007, user-defined-functions, vba

I was trying to add some help to my user-defined function(UDF) in Excel, written using VBA(Visual Basic for Applications). I know how to add a description.Any idea how I can add help at the blue link "Help on this function" and not have it lead to a MsgBox that reads "No help available" ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to first create a help file. You can then use `Application.MacroOptions` to attach the help file to the function

For example

```
Application.MacroOptions Macro:="MyFunction", _
                         Category:="My Custom Category", _
                         HelpFile:="C:\MyHelp.chm", _
                         HelpContextID:=1
```

**EDIT**: Adding More Information

I usually use [Help and Manual6](http://www.helpandmanual.com/) to create my help files for my projects. Here is one example that I created for the above example. And when I click on the "Help On this Function", see what do I get...

[image]

**DISCLAIMER**: I am not connected to **Help and Manual6** in any way but I like their product (It is not free). You might just find a freeware on the web which can make chm files for you so I leave the decision with you on how you choose to make the help file.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough description, I learned something today :)