# How to show hints when writing function in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Every built-in Excel functions has a hint when typing

For example,something like

```
=SUM([Number1,Number2,....
```

I wonder if it is possible to implement something like this when writing customized function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you cannot do that. What you can do however is add descriptions to your UDFs.

Having said that you can use `Application.MacroOptions` to add descriptions. For example

```
Sub Sample()
    Application.MacroOptions Macro:="MyFunction", _
                         Description:="This function does Blah Blah", _
                         Category:="My Custom Category"
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

If you want, you can also add a help file to it as shown in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987037/add-help-to-no-help-available-excel-vba-user-defined-functions).

Comment: Rout as always, you provided great answer.