# Application.MacroOptions and Error 1004

Tags: function, excel, user-defined-functions, vba

I want to register a function kind of `CalculateHours(work_hour, rest_hour)` to Excel VBA, in an Addin like Works.xla

I tried using `Application.MacroOptions` to register the function. The following code is in a `Class` file, the function is in another module file. They would load when we open Excel and the Addin.

**Code:**

```
Private Function AddFunctions()    
    With MyFunction       
        Application.MacroOptions .Name, _
            .Description, , , , , .Category, , , .HelpFilePath                
    End With    
End Function
```

**Expectation:**

I wanna get the argument help, function description in Excel function wizard as other built-in functions. With the help button link to my help file.

**Result:**

```
Error number: 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error
```

or

```
Method "MacroOptions" of object "_Application" failed
```

Is there anything (or everything) wrong?

I have kind of 10 functions and need to add them automatically to Excel function wizard every time load the Addin.

Comment: See if this link helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987037/add-help-to-no-help-available-excel-vba-user-defined-functions

Comment: For tagging, please consider http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62868/is-tagging-a-question-excel-vba-preferable-to-tagging-it-excel-vba

Comment: @SiddharthRout I change the calling of parameters, the error is still there. Help file is not what I concerned but the error :)

Comment: Can you update the code that you are currently using. Also instead of registering the function from the Class Module, try and register it from the `Workbook_Open()` event of the Add-In

Comment: @SiddharthRout it worths a try. Thanks you for helping me many times :)

Comment: No Probs, Simply let us know how it goes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible issue (and solution) that was affecting me... The function code needs to be written in a **module** - if it it written in the `ThisWorkbook` page, Excel won't be able to find the code.

For ease of future readers, here is a compilation of the multiple answers (i.e. list of potential things to check)...

1. The function code needs to be written in a **module** (not `ThisWorkbook`)
2. Make sure the [function description does not exceed 255 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38338847/15919675)
3. If defined in another workbook, [try including the workbook name - e.g. `Macro:="'PERSONAL.xlsb'!Macro/UDF_Name"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63737433/15919675)
4. If defined in an Excel add-in, [call `ThisWorkbook.Activate` before `Application.MacroOptions`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73885723/15919675)

Hope this helps, please one-up the respective solution poster if their answer helped you

Answer (score 6):

07/12/2016 well after dragging my function around following pieces of advise from some posts and doing a number of other pointless things, I found this error happens if Application.MacroOptions Description:=FuncDesc exceeds 255 characters. So essentially don't get too verbose with the description of your user defined function, or just add a

If Len(FuncDesc) > 255 then
Scary warning message about Run-time error '1004'
End if

Comment: Wow. That's good to hear a solution even when I have left the project years ago. I'm not sure this is the case of my original issue so I can't mark it as answer. But have my upvote instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I understand that question is old, but will post my solution to this error, as it may be common and exception message is not informative.
I fixed it with passing a macro/UDF-holder workbook name into "Macro" parameter, like "'Workbook.xls(x/m/b)'!Macro/UDF_Name":

```vb
' Adding a macro from Personal.xlsb
Application.MacroOptions _
                             Macro:="'PERSONAL.xlsb'!Macro/UDF_Name", _
                             Description:="Description", _
                             ArgumentDescriptions:=ArgumentsDescription()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another observation: if the Application.MacroOptions in being run from VBA add-in with ThisWorkbook.IsAddin = True e. g. from Workbook_AddinInstall or Workbook_AddinUninstall, and there is no other workbook opened, Excel throws error 1004. Problem can be solved if one calls ThisWorkbook.Activate before calling Application.MacroOptions.